# Using profiles with ipython/jupyter

Tags: ipython

Here is help output from ipython:

> ### Examples
>
> ```
> ipython notebook                       # start the notebook
> ipython notebook --profile=sympy       # use the sympy profile
> ipython notebook --certfile=mycert.pem # use SSL/TLS certificate
> ```

Seems straightforward .. but then when invoking

```
$ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
```

The following warning occurs:

```
[W 20:54:38.623 NotebookApp] Unrecognized alias: '--profile=pyspark', 
                            it will probably have no effect.
```

So then the online help is inconsistent with the warning message.

What is the correct way to activate the profile?

**Update**  I tried reversing the order as follows:

```
$ipython --profile=pyspark notebook
```

But then a different warning occurs:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'notebook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online docs are inaccurate. The order needs to be reversed - with the -- option before `notebook`:

```
$ipython --profile=pyspark notebook
```

But .. the issues go beyond that even ..

It seems that jupyter (newer version of ipython) may not respect ipython profiles at all.

There are multiple references to same. Here is one from the Spark mailing list

> Does anyone have a pointer to Jupyter configuration with pyspark? The
>   current material on python inotebook is out of date, and jupyter
>   ignores ipython profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The option is for the `ipython` binary, but you are trying to pass the option to the `notebook` application, as evident from the warning, which is from `NotebookApp`:

> [W 20:54:38.623 NotebookApp] Unrecognized alias: '--profile=pyspark', 
>                               it will probably have no effect.

That's basically saying you are passing an option to notebook which it doesn't recognize, so it won't have any effect.

You need to pass the option to ipython:

```
ipython --profile=foo -- notebook
```

Comment: As in my own answer, i did reverse the order (contrary to online docs). However the following now occurs:  "[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'notebook"

Comment: The `--` indicates end of switches. Try the updated version.

Comment: Between profile issues (not supported in jupyter) and pyspark specific issues (getting some spark related env vars to be recognized) I'm really stuck right now.  Both the cloudera and hortonworks blogs/tutorials are out of date - showing usage of ipython profiles. Even comments are not working.

Comment: Its probably because you are running the latest version (ie, jupyter) while the tutorials are for an older version.

Comment: yes that's the case. I must use the latest version of jupyter due to that is our deployment environment.

Comment: I am going to give you an upvote for the input in any case.